# <context-param> in java based configuration

Tags: spring-mvc

Below is the web.xml of my project.

```
<web-app> <listener> <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> </listener>   <context-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value> /WEB-INF/config/applicationContext-service.xml /WEB-INF/config/applicationContext-dao.xml </param-value> </context-param> <servlet> <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> <init-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value> /WEB-INF/config/servlet-context.xml ***/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml*** </param-value> </init-param> <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> </servlet>   </web-app>
```

If I want to convert my project into java based configuration, I know that webapplicationcontext can be configured by using AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer or webapplicationinitializer.
But how can i configure context-param using java configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is you can use servlet context to store the param name and param values by using setattribute and getattribute methods of servlet context by which you can acess them any where throughout your application and check this for more clarification.

https://www.javatpoint.com/servletcontext